# CSS/HTML image not responding to the width and text-align

Tags: html, css

So I've been trying to make myself a personal portfolio, however I've run into issues regarding that. Whenever I try to resize my image using the `width` thing in CSS3, my image does not respond. I've tried resizing it to 25%, 50%, 75%, and nothing works!

Here's my code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: white;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
/*Nav Styles*/
.brand {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 15px;
}
.nav-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 38px;
}
.left-side {
    display:flex;
}
.nav-wrapper > .left-side > div {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-link-wrapper {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 15px;
    height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}
.nav-link-wrapper a {
    color: #8a8a8a;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s
}
.nav-link-wrapper:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.nav-link-wrapper a:hover {
    color:black
}
/*About Page Styles*/
.profile-image-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
}
.profile-content-wrapper {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.profile-content-wrapper h1 {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 22px;
}
.profile-content-wrapper p {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 15px;
}
.profile-content-wrapper h4 {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Mika's Portfolio</title>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium Web' rel='stylesheet'>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class = "left-side">
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "right-side">
                <div class="brand">
                    <div>
                        MIKA TAN
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-image-wrapper">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/16/20/30/lighthouse-5577451_1280.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="profile-content-wrapper">
          <h1>
            Hey there!
          </h1>
          <p>
            Now you've got a quick look around my website, think about hiring me to make you your own website!
          </p>
          <p>
              Thanks, have a great day.
          </p>
          <h4>
              GMAIL:
          </h4>
          <p>
              mikayxtan@gmail.com
          </p>
        </div> 
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

My image called mika.png is in a class called `profile-image-wrapper`, and also does not respond to the `text-align: center;` thing.

I have tried in-line style coding, which works to an extent (however I prefer to not have to use in-line style so I can create a media query later), and I have used the !important attribute for CSS which only works for `text-align` and not the `width`.

Comment: Please add [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: considered giving the width to the actual img instead of the parent? i assume your parent allows overflow wich means setting a width on the parent won't affect the child(the img in this case) atall

Comment: Just add `.profile-image-wrapper img { width: 100%;} ` Otherwise image will take its default size and not container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your image responsive you should give it a `max-width: 100%` right now it follows the width of the container and it stays inside of it. So add this new piece of code.

```
.profile-image-wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

now the image fills 50% of the width as you wanted to do. Now if you want your image to be in the middle with 50% width just add `margin: 0 auto;` to the image wrapper and you should be good to go.

```
.profile-image-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

if you want the image to be fill width you can remove the width 50% from the wrapper.

with 50% width applied to the wrapper

[image: result1]

without the 50% width on the wrapper, it would look something like this.

[image: result2]

Note that in both cases the image is responsive duo to the fact you added `max-width:100%` to the `img` tag.

That's not what you are looking for? please let me know and show me a screenshot of the desired output.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I can change the width and now it'll respond.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 .profile-image-wrapper img{
     width:15%
  }
```

Comment: Works to fix the `width` thing but doesn't work for the text-align.

Answer (score 0):

Please set `margin: 0 auto;` for `.profile-image-wrapper` selector to make center horizontally.

Please set `display: inline-block;` CSS in `.profile-image-wrapper img` selector

**Updated snippet :-**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mika's Portfolio</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium Web' rel='stylesheet'>
    
</head>
<style>
    body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: white;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
/*Nav Styles*/
.brand {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 15px;
}
.nav-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 38px;
}
.left-side {
    display:flex;
}
.nav-wrapper > .left-side > div {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-link-wrapper {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 15px;
    height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}
.nav-link-wrapper a {
    color: #8a8a8a;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s
}
.nav-link-wrapper:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.nav-link-wrapper a:hover {
    color:black
}
/*About Page Styles*/
.profile-image-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%; margin:0 auto;
}

.profile-image-wrapper img{ width:50%; display: inline-block;}
.profile-content-wrapper {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.profile-content-wrapper h1 {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 22px;
}
.profile-content-wrapper p {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 15px;
}
.profile-content-wrapper h4 {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';font-size: 15px;
}

</style>
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class = "left-side">
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "right-side">
                <div class="brand">
                    <div>
                        MIKA TAN
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="profile-image-wrapper">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/HPrl3u8.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="profile-content-wrapper">
            <h1>
                Hey there!
            </h1>
            <p>
                Now you've got a quick look around my website, think about hiring me to make you your own website!
            </p>
            <p>
                Thanks, have a great day.
            </p>
            <h4>
                GMAIL:
            </h4>
            <p>
                mikayxtan@gmail.com
            </p>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```